# While 'frame dragging' is the 'frame' just orbiting or is it even spiralling into the source of gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, frame-dragging

While 'frame dragging' is the 'frame' just orbiting or is it even spiralling into the source of gravity causing anti-dark-energy effect?

Comment: Is your question about orbiting motion, or about the special case where the motion of the object with respect to the source of gravity is such that it will collide with the gravity source (and hence will join that larger body).

Comment: @Cleonis I am asking about the frame rotation,is it falling inside the source considering the possibility that 'dark energy' acting throughout the universe may be causing 'pressure' on the frame so it slowly finishes in the grav.source...Or the frame is intact and just rotating around the grav.source?

Comment: It depends on your frame: loosely speaking a frame is nothing but an idealized observer (that may be inertial or accelerating) with some 3-versor system attached. Please define "frame rotation".

Comment: As pointed out by Quillo, a frame of reference is defined relative to some object that is in motion. In a solar system: one can choose to represent motion with respect to a solar-system-wide coordinate system that is co-moving with the center of mass of that solar system. Or one can zoom in and use some local representation; a coordinate system that is co-moving with some object that is a member of that system. Zooming in and zooming out one can assess differences.

Answer (score 1):

During frame dragging the frame does spiral into the source of gravity and that how gravity works. The frame rotates because of the rotation of the gravitational body and the dragging is the cause of different bodies getting gravitationaly attracted to each other.

Comment: Frame dragging means that the abstract (ideal) frames are "dragged" by the rotation of the central object (loosely speaking, they tend to revolve around the object even if they have zero angular momentum).

Answer (score 0):

The frame dragging does not impart a sideways velocity. That is: if the infalling motion is straight towards the center of gravity to  begin with then the rotation of the source of the gravity will not manifest itself in the form of imparting sideways velocity.

What the frame dragging *will* do is that as the infalling object is traveling through the gravitational field it will rotate around its own center of mass.

(Of course, a rotation sensor (such as a gyroscope) that is co-moving with the object, hence *local* measurement, will not detect rotation. The motion through the gravitational field is inertial motion.)

Reference:
Andrew J. S. Hamilton and Jason P. Lisle, 2006 "[The river model of black holes](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0411060)"
Journal reference:  Am.J.Phys.76:519-532,2008

Comment: None of this is correct. If it was the Gravity Probe B experiment would not have been successful. Not to mention the accretion disk around black holes would not rotate the way that they do.